# How to Stop Click Event Bubbling With e.stopPropagation() in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a div which is wrapped in a Link tag in NextJS.  Within the div I have a row of components which are buttons. When I click one of these buttons, they do what they should do, but the Link tag also gets fired from the parent div and we navigate to another page. I have added e.stopPropagation() to the event handlers of the buttons, but it's not making any difference. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong, please?

The parent component:

```
<Link href={{
    pathname: `/...`,
    query: { 
        var:var 
    },
}}>
    <div>
    ...
        <div className="flex flex-row">
            <Button1/>
            <Button2/>
        </div>
    </div>    
</Link>
```

A child button component:

```
async function handleClick(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    ...
}

<button onClick={handleClick}>
...
</button>
```

I have also tried adding adding the stopPropagation to the onClick as such:

```
<button onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation(), handleClick}>
...
</button>
```

Why is the click still bubbling up to the parent Link, please?

Comment: What is the idea behind this? Pure curiosity, because i would never do something like this  exactly because of this behavior that you are getting.

Comment: I would like the whole container div to act as a link, but within that div there are buttons to do stuff. Think of a tweet in Twitter, which is a link in itself, and then the like, retweet buttons etc. I know it's not ideal, but stopPropagation should handle this from what I have read

Comment: Write some kind of wrapper, inside put your link and your buttons...?

Comment: @RayPurchase You're `<Link>` element will render to `<a>` but if you open Twitter and inspect the DOM you will see that a tweet is technically not a link, it's just a `<div>` with an associated event handler.  Use a generic `<div>` and handle the routing imperatively.

Comment: Thanks Ibsn, this actually fixes the problem. Something about having an anchor tag meant it fired off even with RemyHo's answer below, despite that technically being correct too. However, removing the Next Link and replacing with a div and using Next router which is called on a click event on the div solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

here is the culprit:

```
<button onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation(), handleClick}>
```

try:

```
<button onClick={(e) => { e.stopPropagation(); handleClick(); }>
```

live demo on these two different versions:
https://codepen.io/remyho427/pen/NWamxvG

Comment: Can you explain the difference?